# easyimap - connect to gmail fails with invalid credentials

Tags: python, gmail, imap, gmail-imap, imaplib

i'm trying to connect to my gmail account via imap with easyimap (0.6.3), but I got all the time ***error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'*** .

My code is simple:

```
import easyimap
imapper = easyimap.connect(host, 'username@gmail.com', 'password', 'INBOX.subfolder')
```

. By default port 993 is used and SSL is True.

I'm absolutely sure my password is correct, and I also tried to use username instead of username@gmail.com - same results.

In the gmail setting I turned on IMAP (Status: IMAP is enabled) which might be kinda important, but not enough.

What else can I do if my credentials are correct? I don't have much knowledge about gmail, and this was used only for mailing (through the web interface), nothing else. I can't sign in to admin.gmail.com (it accepts the credentials, but does nothing), so I'm unsure if (and how) i need to enables less secure app access .

What else could I do to find out what is the problem?

Python: 3.5.2 .

Thanks.

Comment: And i've the same result using IMAPLIB, so most probably the problem is somewhere in the gmail settings, but where?

Comment: You need to either enable Less Secure Apps, generate an App Specific Passwords, or register and implement Oauth2.  If you're running your program on a public cloud, it probably won't work without Oauth2   Gmail really doesn't want you to use basic passwords.

Comment: Check [OAuth 2.0 Mechanism](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol).

Comment: It'd run from my server, or from my local machine. (1) How can I enable less secure apps (in this case it really does not matter), or (2) where should I register and implement Oauth2?

Comment: Accidentally I found this link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1 , which lets me enable less secure apps without having access to admin.google.com access.